# remove line break from each element in python

Tags: python, list, readlines

I open a text file, now each element in the text file is separated by a line break. when I use `readlines()` It keeps this line break in the list, this is after each element so as it looks like this `[zebra\n, ant\n,]` i was wondering whether there is a easy function or piece of coding that I could use to just strip all the elements of this line break!

this is the code i have written so far

```
filelist=file.readlines()
file.close()
return filelist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
filelist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
```

Comment: 'filelist=file.readlines()
        file.close()
        return filelist'
this is what i have written so far how would i implement it in to this?

Comment: which one, this is what ive written so far `        for line in file.readlines():
            line.rstrip('\n')
        filelist=file.readlines()
        file.close()`

Comment: it just prints blank when i do it if i remove either of them and even when i put them back it prints nothing